# Scala Play framework enable only certain filters

Tags: scala, filter, playframework

I am trying to enable only one Play filter, while disabling other ones (like host filtering, or CSRF filtering).

This is my `application.conf file`:

```
play.http.filters=<filter that I am enabling>
play.filters.disabled+=play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
play.filters.disabled+=play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
```

It seems like after I've added the line `play.http.filters=<filter that I am enabling>` at the very beginning, the disabled filters got enabled again, as I see familiar error messages:

```
Illegal 'x-forwarded-for' header: Invalid input ':', expected listSep or 'EOI' (line 1, column 13)
```

What is a correct way of disabling certain filters and enabling certain filters in scala play framework?

Answer (score 1):

In play 2.6, disabling/enabling default filters are done by changig application.conf. To enable default filter, should add [play.filters.enabled](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Filters#default-filters). To disable default filter you should add [play.filters.disabled](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Filters#disabling-default-filters).

I think there is some confusion here. [play.http.filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaHttpFilters#using-filters) should be fully qualified class name of the class in your app. This class becomes responsible for enabling/disabling filters. Here is simple example of filter who respects play.filters.enabled/disabled configuration:

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters
import play.api.http.EnabledFilters
import play.api.mvc.{EssentialAction, EssentialFilter}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

// Our example filter
@Singleton
class ExampleFilter @Inject()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends EssentialFilter {
  override def apply(next: EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { request =>
    next(request).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders("X-ExampleFilter" -> "foo")
    }
  }
}

// All our filters
class Filters @Inject()(
   defaultFilters: EnabledFilters, // respect play.filters.enabled and play.filters.disabled
   exampleFilter: ExampleFilter, // you can pass user-defined filter
) extends DefaultHttpFilters(defaultFilters.filters: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the only filter I would like to have is not a default filter, but a filter from a 3rd party library. It looks like play.filters.enabled would only work for default play filters. In this case, how could I enable not a default filter? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.6, you should be able to do `play.filters.enabled=[youDesiredFilter]` as described in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Filters#Disabling-Default-Filters).

Only the filters in that list will be enabled. All default filters will be disabled if they are not listed.